# How to make the loop to get to the end and stop at the end?

Tags: unity, c#

This is what I'm trying to archive and it's almost working fine :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using FIMSpace.FLook;

public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    public FLookAnimator lookAnimator;
    public Transform[] targets;
    public float switchingTime;
    public bool switchingLoop = false;

    private bool loopOnce = true;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    private void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(SwitchTargetsPeriodically());
    }

    private void Update()
    {

    }

    IEnumerator SwitchTargetsPeriodically()
    {
        for (int i = 0; true; i = (i + 1) % targets.Length)
        {
            if (i < targets.Length - 1 && switchingLoop)
            {
                loopOnce = true;

                lookAnimator.ObjectToFollow = targets[i];
            }

            if (switchingLoop == false && loopOnce)
            {
                if (i < targets.Length - 1)
                {
                    lookAnimator.ObjectToFollow = targets[i];  
                }
                else
                {
                    loopOnce = false;
                }
            }

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(switchingTime);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem it's looping the targets.Length - 1 and if I change it to targets.Length then it will not loop at all. but if I'm doing targets.Length - 1 it will loop between 3 targets but there is 4 targets.

Comment: Can you edit your last sentence "but I want to do that if the switchingLoop is false changed to false at run time then loop to the last target and stop there at the last target don't start over again." I'm having a hard time understanding what behavior it is that you want.

Comment: @Charly edited my question with the last code what I did and what is the problem.  The problem is that if I'm doing in both places targets.Length - 1 it will loop only on 3 targets out of 4 but if I'm doing targets.Length then it will not loop at all.

Comment: Imagine how much more quickly you could have solved this if you described this requirement in your original question.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. not sure if it's the best way but it's working as I wanted.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    public FLookAnimator lookAnimator;
    public Transform[] targets;
    public float switchingTime;
    public bool switchingLoop = false;

    private bool loopOnce = true;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    private void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(SwitchTargetsPeriodically());
    }

    private void Update()
    {

    }

    IEnumerator SwitchTargetsPeriodically()
    {
        for (int i = 0; true; i = (i + 1) % targets.Length)
        {
            if (i <= targets.Length - 1 && switchingLoop)
            {
                loopOnce = true;

                lookAnimator.ObjectToFollow = targets[i];
            }

            if (switchingLoop == false && loopOnce)
            {
                if (i <= targets.Length - 1)
                {
                    lookAnimator.ObjectToFollow = targets[i];  
                }
                
                if(i == (targets.Length - 1))
                {
                    loopOnce = false;
                }
            }

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(switchingTime);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this really strange for-loop, I would just create an infinite while-loop and nest a regular for-loop within it which iterates once through all the targets:

```
IEnumerator SwitchTargetsPeriodically()
{
    while (true)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < targets.Length; i++)
        {
            lookAnimator.ObjectToFollow = targets[i];
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(switchingTime);
        }
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

In case you wonder what the `yield return null` after the for-loop does: This covers the edge-case that there are 0 targets. Without that line, the game would freeze because the while-loop would spin forever without an interruption. The `yield return null` causes the coroutine to pause until the next frame, when there might perhaps be a target.